# can't sort data for February 2016 by week number in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, date, reporting-services

For some reason when I break down 12 month by week in SSRS the month February looks weird. Weeks starting from 10, then it goes 6,7,8,9.
It sorted by WeekNumber A to Z.
[image]

[image]

Why does it looks like that only for February? How can I fix it?

My data in SSMS look like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks like your week 'numbers' are being interpreted as string data. A big clue is that the week numbers are left aligned in the report (left align is the default for string data, right align is default for numeric). Also '1' comes before '6' so in a string sort '1', '10', '100' would all come before '2' or '3' etc.

Comment: you were correct. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

My week 'numbers' were interpreted as string data. 
In a sorting tab I used expression: `=Cint(Fields!WeekNumber.Value)` 
and it worked.